# Cannot boot from hard drive

Tags: linux, boot, bios

The computer can boot from CD and USB, but cannot boot from hard drive. The hard drive is in the bootable list in BIOS, but the computer just reboots again and again. I reinstalled the OS (fedora), but it does not work.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what happens when you try to boot from the hard drive? Do you get any sort of error message?

Comment: Thank you guys! I cannot test it recently. As I remember, there is a phoenix bios status page congaing memory size and CPU information, and it says press any key to continue, and then there is a cursor on the top right conner of the screen. Then it reboots.. No error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is IDE drive, then look out for jumper settings to select Master or Slave connectivity
2. If it is SSD, try different cables and connecting to different port in the machine
3. Sometimes, reconnecting the cables for couple of times would help in addressing the issue
4. Finally, try isolating the issue by taking the Hard Drive and plugging it in the other machine and confirm it whether it is an issue with Hard drive or machine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue before on Dell machines. If your machine is a Dell, check the Sata Operation menu and change the setting from RAID Autodetect / ATA to RAID Autodetect / AHCI or the other way around depending on which it is set to.

This has resolved the issue for me before. There should be a similar Sata Operations menu on other BIOS types besides Dell but I have no experience dealing with them.

For your personal reference this issue is called a perpetual reboot.

I would be able to help you more if you gave us information such as the manufacturer of the computer, the BIOS version, and the age of the computer.

Also, it is important to know whether or not the hard drive is a SATA (thin cable, only connects to one drive) or a PATA (big cable, connects to 2 drives).

Comment: Sorry I don't know the manufacturer of the computer. I think the computer is about 10 years, and the BIOS version is phoenix b4985 v3.00B.b30. In fact I just tried to install window 7, and it worked! But after I installed Linux, it cannot boot again. This time I installed arch linux, and I see "GRUB loading.." on the screen and then it reboot. When I installed fedora, I only saw a cursor, and it reboot.  The hard drive is SATA